# Compute the difference between 2 triangle volumes in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to create a function in scheme that will allow me to compute the difference between two triangle volumes using a function i already created to compute the volume of the triangle. Here is what i have. I cannot get the diffVol function to work.

```
(define (triArea base height)
 (*
  (/ base 2) height
 ) 
)

(define (triVol base height depth)
  (*
   (triArea base height) depth
  )
 )

(define diffVol
  (let
      ( (volume1 triVol))
    (let
       ( (volume2 triVol))
         (- volume1 volume2)
       )
   )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `volume1` and `volume2`, you're not applying `triVol` to any arguments

Also, `diffVol` needs parameters if it's going to be a reusable function

You could do this one of two ways.

**A)** `diffVol` takes two volumes

```
(define (diff-volume a b)
  (- a b))

(diff-volume (triVol 4 5 6) (triVol 7 8 9)) ;=> -192
```

**B)** `diffVol` could take the dimensions for two separate triangles, then compute the difference

```
(define (diff-volume base1 height1 depth1 base2 height2 depth2)
  (- (triVol base1 height1 depth1)
     (triVol base2 height2 depth2)))

(diff-volume 4 5 6 7 8 9) ;=> - 192
```

Solution `A` is a much better solution. Solution B requires way too many parameters and you're likely to forget what order they go in.

---

**Remarks**

*Naming:* Scheme/Racket doesn't use camelCase. They use lowercase names with hyphens separating words/terms. Predicate procedures should end in a `?`.

*Indenting:* Scheme/Racket has pretty strong opinions on how you should indent things. It looks like you're trying to make your scheme look like a language you're used to work in.

Here's some general improvements on naming/indenting

```
(define (tri-area base height)
 (* (/ base 2) height))

(define (tri-vol base height depth)
  (* (tri-area base height) depth))

(define (diff-volume a b)
  (- a b))

(diff-volume (tri-vol 4 5 6)
             (tri-vol 7 8 9))
```

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate your response. My assignment states "Define a procedure called “DiffVol” that will compute the difference in volume for 2 triangles. You must use TriVol procedure defined in question 4. Because the values for base, height, and depth are read in TriVol, there are not parameters and there is no need to read any input. You will need to modify your printing procedure to also return the printed value for this procedure to work properly. For this assignment, a negative output is acceptable." I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: "Because the values for base, height, and depth are read in TriVol, there are not parameters and there is no need to read any input." This is the part that doesn't make any sense. If these are the exact words of your instructor, I'd say he/she has no idea how to effectively talk about computer programs. The only way `diff-vol` can know which two volumes to compute the difference of is by having parameters.

Comment: Yea i agree,  this is pulled straight from the homework. I don't know how we can use the difVol function can work without parameters.

Comment: The only way you could is if you use free variables, but then it's a completely senseless procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with. This seems to be what the instructor wants. Thanks for your help on this i really appreciate it.

```
(define (diffVol volume1 volume2)
        (display "The volume difference is: ")
        (- volume1 volume2 )
   )


 (diffVol (triVol (read) (read) (read))
    (triVol (read) (read) (read))
  )
```